# Creating an array content with dictionaries using NSXMLParsing in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parsing, nsxmlparser

Afternoon overflowers,

In my code, I'm trying to parse and SOAP response that is in NSData format. With that data, using NSXMLParse, I'm trying to create an array of dictionaries. The problem is, anytime I add my new dictionary to the array, it replaces the old dictionary object contents with the currently added one. For instance, at the end of the parse, I have 7 dictionaries with the same content in my array. Here is the code to show what I have done;

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Received the SOAP data.");

    if (!itemArray) {
        itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        itemArray = nil;
        itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    if (!itemDictionary) {
        itemDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        itemDictionary = nil;
        itemDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"Started Element %@", elementName);
    element = [NSMutableString string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if(element == nil) {
        element = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    [element appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"Found an element named: %@ with a value of: %@", elementName, element);

    if (![elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [itemDictionary setValue:element forKey:elementName];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        if (itemDictionary) {
            [itemArray addObject:itemDictionary];

            [itemDictionary removeAllObjects];
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[itemArray addObject:itemDictionary];
[itemDictionary removeAllObjects];
```

Try:

```
[itemArray addObject:itemDictionary];
itemDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

So instead of removing all of the items from your dictionary you create a new dictionary for the next set of content.

Answer (score 0):

i think you expected as each itemDictionary is a individual object which needs to store in itemArray. So you have to create the dictionay instance once you start the element. try like this

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"Started Element %@", elementName);
    itemDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    element = [NSMutableString string];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call removeAllObjects, it just use the same instance of dictionary which your array is adding. When you modify your dictionary it modify the same dictionary your array contains(since both is actually same), so instead of calling removeAllObjects, create new dictionary everytime when new element starts.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"Started Element %@", elementName);
    itemDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    element = [NSMutableString string];
}
```